# detect certificate bundle usable by OpenSSL

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate

Is there any way how to find the path of the certificate bundle (e.g., `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`) by running the `openssl` (or any other) command and parsing some of its output? It there any other way, without running the `openssl` command?

I want to find the path during product installation so that I can provide reasonable default settings.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is: you can parse the output of

```
openssl version -a
```

Sample output:

```
built on: Thu Mar 14 02:45:44 NZDT 2013
platform: linux-elf
options:  bn(64,32) rc4(1x,char) des(ptr,risc1,16,long) blowfish(idx) 
compiler: gcc -Wl,--as-needed,-O1,--hash-style=both  -DPURIFY -fPIC -DOPENSSL_PIC -DZLIB_SHARED -DZLIB -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -Wa,--noexecstack -DL_ENDIAN -DTERMIO -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -Wall -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_PART_WORDS -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DRMD160_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/local/Libraries/OpenSSL/x86/1.0.1c/gcc-4.7.2/ssl"
```

You can see that the last line shows you the directory where you can find your **certs** subdirectory, which is probably what you're looking for.

I have no idea whether there is any other way of obtaining this information (*OPENSSLDIR* is a compilation flag after all).

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not seem to be available everywhere. I have a HP-UX with OpenSSL 0.9.6i, that I have to support as well, that does not have the line in the `openssl version -a`.